# Justified bootstrap menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I try to do a site header. The logo width = 405px. Also a header and a menu under it, of same width (100%-405px).

something like this:

[image]

The menu should be **justified**... and apparentrly this is not supported by bootstrap...

I tried to use flex, but is not supported by IE 11...

Here is **[my fiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/serhiol/d7grky27/2/)** and the main extract:

```
<div class="cotnainer-fluid">

  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="top-header"> welcome and ...login right</div>
    <div class="menu">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">  ...  </nav>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main container">...</div>
</div>
```

How do I fix this code to be a) at least Chrome compatible, b) IE11 compatible.

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#nav-justified

Comment: @99tharun, it says in the linked doc: `Justified navbar nav links are currently not supported.`

Answer (score 0):

The .logo will need a `display: inline-block` so that it doesn't force other elements below it ( elements are `display: block` by default most browsers).

Next I'd recommend wrapping both the .top-header and .menu in a div element where you can apply the css calc as well as the pull-left/pull-right.

Just to make certain the .top-header and .menu fill the new container I added a `width: 100%` as well.

Here's an [updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeremyhawes/d7grky27/3/).

Note, the link and list item with the "Login" link is now covered, but that's likely a separate issue.